# Actualizar componente tras cambio de url - React

Tags: reactjs

Tengo el siguiente código. Consigo que con el shouldcomponentupdate actualice el this.state.path cada vez que cambie de url, pero no consigo que el component se actualice y por ejemplo si estoy en películas, y le doy a juegos, me salga la lista de juegos, me siguen saliendo las películas. Vamos, que el fetch no se ejecuta de nuevo. Que deberia hacer?

```
  state = {
    data: [],
    path:this.props.match.path
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.path !== this.props.match.url) {
     this.setState({
       path: this.props.match.url
     });
     this.componentDidMount();
    }
  }

  loadData = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080"+this.state.path)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status !== 200) {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch posts.");
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((resData) => {
          console.log(resData);
        this.setState({
          data: resData.movies || resData.games || resData.series
        });
      })
      .catch(this.catchError);
  };
```

Comment: No será componentDidUpdate??

Comment: Eso no me funciona, debo darle dos clicks para que cambien el state, y a la segunda se actualice muchas veces a la vez

Comment: Ya halle la solución, la añadí a la pregunta.

Comment: Añade tu solución en la sección de respuestas para que sea una publicación más ordenada.